# How do I create new java project in eclipse EE?

Tags: eclipse

I used eclipse IDE for Java developers to make java projects. I wanted to try the same thing on Eclipse Java EE. But, it does not have any such option. Looks like it only lets you create EE projects like servlets, JPA,  EJB etc.

Is it possible to create standard java projects in Eclipse EE ?

The answer below works and I see the screen -

[image]

Comment: About the edit: did you try to click "Yes"?

Comment: @JBert - haha yes. Just wanted to make it like a tut for ppl who search for this later. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to click `File -> New -> Other`? The menu is context sensitive, it changes when you switch your *perspective*. 
 "Other" will open the "New" wizard, in which case you can select `Java -> Java Project` from the list.

You could also click `Windows -> Perspective -> Open perspective -> Other` (or `Java`) from the list to switch back to the default Java perspective. That way, your IDE will look it does in the "Java developers" edition.

EDIT: In case you haven't noticed these UI tricks of Eclipse before, you might want to read this [tutorial section on Eclipse perspectives](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse/eclipse_tutorial_3.5.html#section5_0).